# Monte Carlo integration

Tags: r, monte-carlo, integral

I am calculating a simple integral $\int^1_{-2} \exp{x^2}(x+1)dx $
with Monte Carlo method using a linear density function $p_\xi (x) = \frac{4}{9} + \frac{2}{9} x $. Let say I have a a sample which is distributed on the interval [0,1]. In order it to be distributed on interval [-2,1] I integrated it, following the algorithm of calculation,

$\int\limits_0^{\xi}  \frac{4}{9} + \frac{2}{9} x dx= U $
After solving the equation  I get  $\xi = \sqrt{9 \cdot U + 4} – 2$
. As ξ should be from [-2,1], I transformed  a little bit the equation, so my final result was $\xi = \frac{3(\sqrt{9 \cdot U + 4} – 2 )}{\sqrt{13} – 2} – 2 $,
where U is random variable from my sample.
The rule says that the approximation of integral should be
$I \approx \frac{1}{n} \sum \limits^n_{i=1} \exp({\xi_i^2})(\xi_i +1 ) \cdot \frac{1}{p_{\xi} (\xi_i)} $ 
Where n is a number of random variables in U.

I have tried to calculate it with R, but I always get a wrong answer. The true result is -8.02465, but I get -1163.554. I don‘t know where exactly my mistake is, whether it is in my R code or the algorithm.
R code:

```
x1=c()
x1[1]=1
a=1141
c=247
b=a-1
m=1216
for (i in 1:(m-1)){
x1[i+1]=(a*x1[i]+c)%%m}


m=1216
x=c()
int=c()
U=x1/m
for(i in 1:m){
x[i]=sqrt(9*U[i])-2
int[i]=exp(x[i]^2)*(x[i]+1)/(4+2*x[i])
}
I=9/m*sum(int)
I
```

Comment: The correct formula is $\xi = \sqrt{9u}-2$. Note that since $p_\xi$ gets close to zero, this method of estimating an integral is extremely variable, because a few of the values of $1/p_\xi(\xi_i)$ will likely be huge. They can cause your estimate to depart from the correct value of $\int_{-2}^1\left(\exp(x^2)\right)(x+1)dx.$ For instance, when you use $n=10^6$ the values of $I$ will still fluctuate between $-9$ and $-7$ most of the time (and on occasion will be well outside even that wide interval). Finally, your code cannot be checked because it won't run: `x1` is undefined.

Comment: I have edited my original code, providing x1. This is a sample that I have to use for integrating my function. I have tried to use the correct formula, R gives me -28.70119, it is surely better result than the previous one but still it isn't even close to a true value.

Comment: Your new code is mysterious. Are you trying to roll your own linear congruence pseudo random number generator? *Don't*. Just use `R`'s built-in one. Not only is it easier and faster, it will work much better, too. It's as simple as `U<-runif(m)`. Incidentally, with `m` as small as 1216, there's better than a 1% chance you will compute a value of `I` even worse than -28.7. But before trying this, first fix your integration error!

Comment: Yes, previously I have created pseudo random numbers, I had to use them to calculate the integral. That was the point of my whole project. I have fixed the error and tried to calculate with a big n and I have got quite nice result -7.67